# How to implement in DVMRP, MOSPF in NS2

Tags: network-programming, multicast, network-protocols, ns2, nam

I am trying to implement the above multicast protocol using ns2, but i am unable to find correct source on how to build the protocol.

I read through the documentation, all they said about was Centralised Multicast, Dense Mode, Shared Tree Mode and Bidirectional Shared Mode, but i have no idea as to how to implement DVMRP.

Comment: DV : ns2 is old, not much saved, e.g. NSBench0.9.jar http://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/~cs4cc3/labs/4cc04lb2.pdf .... Edited "test.tcl" / DVMRP_test.tcl → https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GE_60q_8yvr91qG_UmrrgV1FKVBAUaoz/view?usp=share_link → not working! .........  **DV+mcast-ex-7.tar.xz** https://drive.google.com/file/d/199Z1q-jFYRC1yQPjeEHT-IGqKT0AY0H-/view?usp=share_link ....... Hint https://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/doc/node348.html

Comment: MOSPF : ospf patch is available, ospf_ns235.patch https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNbjctSHF5TWduVFU/view?usp=sharing ...... ns2 patches https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNZ2lWZDBRSW40Q00?resourcekey=0-eBw6mJFKhSVGultqaD2rDA&usp=share_link .... ns2 ex https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNSmRYb2lGcDRUdWs?resourcekey=0-vrEMHtGTFP3yLoTQz_UAwA&usp=share_link

Comment: OMNeT++ , DVMRP https://doc.omnetpp.org/inet/api-old/doxy/classinet_1_1_i_multicast_route.html .......... OMNeT++ , dvmrp + mospf https://www.academia.edu/10762234/IPv6_Unicast_and_IPv4_Multicast_Routing_in_OMNeT_

Comment: @KnudLarsen thank you, but how can i use the patch file ??
I want to compare these two protocols, how can i do that? on what basis should i compare

Comment: @KnudLarsen i went through a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=st50WO2hTQA&t=1330s , in this he has talked about 5 files,,
and then i saw   cas.mcmaster.ca/~cs4cc3/labs/4cc04lb2.pdf , this has the code for dvmrp.
I mean what is the difference netween them?
What is happening in these two?
I am really sorry if my doubts seems silly, but is really bugging me

Comment: @KnudLarsen I have one more doubt I read through the documentation, in that  Centralised Multicast, Dense Mode, Shared Tree Mode and Bidirectional Shared Mode were present. what are they ?? protocol or something else?

Comment: About http://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/~cs4cc3/labs/4cc04lb2.pdf : The files are no more, ns2 officially unsupported for 7 years. ..... About "two patches" : I mentioned **one** patch : `cd ns-allinone-2.35/ && patch -p0 < ospf_ns235.patch` ........ ns2 INFO https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dbrFE8CDMNbE5Kmq4duZl6bUTP7PXdVps9AGvzVi0gM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @KnudLarsen how to use the patch and what is the use of using the patch file??

Comment: Please read (again) https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dbrFE8CDMNbE5Kmq4duZl6bUTP7PXdVps9AGvzVi0gM/edit?usp=sharing , page 1-2 to watch "ns-allinone-2.35/ → patch -p0 < ospf_ns235.patch" .... Requirements: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install g++ g++-4.8 autoconf libtool libxmu-dev` ......... The patch is a readable text file ... all "added items" are marked + .